# How to combine bundled and configurable and simple products in magento webshop?

Tags: magento

I want to sell door strikes in a Magento webshop.
The door strike is composed of a front plate and the strike itself.
The front plate is a simple product.
The strike can have different power options, like 8-14 V AC/DC or 12 VDC, or 24 VDC.
So, this has to become a configurable product.
In our ware house the front plates and the various strikes are stocked in separate locations.
So, for each product bought, two order lines (front plate and strike) should appear in the order/packing list.
Moreover, we show our actual stock position in the webshop.
For this combined product either one of the components can limit the total stock position.
The part with the lowest stock position (either the front plate or the strike with the chosen voltage) should be shown in the webshop.
I tried to combine bundled products, configurable products and simple products in several ways, but did not get a solution.
How can I combine the requests above to show one product in the webshop?
For a reference have a look at our webshop: www.deuropener.net

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create 3-layered products, but you can compose this product types in 3 simple steps.

Step 1: For your strikes, create a configurable product as you do usually, except for the "Active" attribute, set it as inactive and the "Visibility" attribute, set it to "Not visible".

Step 2: create your derived products from the previous configurable product in the "Associated products" tab with the "Visibility" attribute, set to "Not visible"

Step 3: For your door strikes, create a bundle product. In the "Bundled items" tab, add 2 options, one for your plates and one for your derived products strikes.

You will have the ease of use of the backend, derived products associations, fine stock management without any complex development

Greg